# Run android emulator x86 using Docker under Mac OS

Tags: android, emulation

I installed *docker.app* on the my and I want to start up android x86 emulator in the docker image.
Unfortunately I met the following error(s) while trying to start the emulator. (emulator @nexus7)

> **ERROR**: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm

Given my Mac OS actually seems to support vmx, **how could I startup android x86 emulator?**

Comment: Consider adding any configuration file(s) that may be helpful like Docker build steps.

Answer (score 4):

The way I've managed to do this (for now) is somewhat convoluted: I've set up an ubuntu vm in Parallels and enabled "nested virtualization"

[image]

With that setting I've managed to spin up and run our Android UI tests via docker on a Mac.

I've yet to figure out how to do that without the additional Parallels VM layer.

Comment: This is great sas. Would you be able to help and provide steps what do i need to do. I am struggling since last 10 days but one or another thing does not work. I have following setup
1. Docker Desktop for Mac
2. VirtualBox (Ubuntu)

there are multiple blogs available but none of them explain clearly what need to be done step by step.
(Do i need to install Docker on this VM or i can continue installing on Mac OSX, and if so, then how to connect docker with VM?)
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: BTW, i am on intel with VirtualBox 6.0 which does not support nested Virtualization.

Comment: I don’t think this works with Virtual Box. I’ve only done this with Parallels, thanks to its settings. Also, you don’t use Docker for Mac but install docker inside your VM, with Ubuntu.